# Jquery .addClass Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some reason, the .addClass method isn't adding that class to the content that was just added to the page via a $(div).prepend method from an AJAX call. I first removed the bold formatting from all the content, and then want to just make the new one bold. Is this an idiosyncrasy of jQuery or am I missing something? Code below:

```
function sess(id,tid) {
$.ajax ({
    method:     "POST",
    url:        'sess.php',
    data:       {"fid":id},
    success:    function(response) {
                    $('.create').show();
                    //docs(id); //previously isolated - not the problem
                    //mess(id,tid); //previously isolated - not the problem
                    //msf(); //previously isolated - not the problem
                    //suppf(); //previously isolated - not the problem
                    //filesf(); //previously isolated - not the problem
                    $('.f').removeClass('bold');
                    $('#f-'+id).addClass('bold');
                    $('#supp-'+id).show();
                }
});
```

}

Comment: What content is returned from the AJAX call?

Comment: Are you talking about bolding the font, or a class named bold

Comment: the content is returned from the previous function. that function returns the content (the information for the added file) to prepend onto the list of current files, and then calls this function to make the new file active

Comment: its a class i made that just has font-weight: bold associated with it. can i not use .bold as a class name?

Comment: If possible , can  post `html` ? Thanks

Comment: this is the html that the previous function returns.                        57^<p><span class="f b" id="f-57">Test</span><br>Test, TEST Test<br>Last action by user<br>01:49 PM, 08/27/2014<br><span class="supp" id="supp-57"><span class="tiny mss" id="mss-57">milestones</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="tiny maps" id="maps-57">map</span></span></p>

Answer (score 0):

figured it out - i was forgetting to parseInt() on the content returned from the previous function, so i was passing a string when the JS was looking for an integer.

my bad. thanks everyone.